# JFrame not working at all

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I'm using netbeans IDE 8.1 in windows 10.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class S1 extends JFrame{
    public S1(){

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 400, 400);
        setResizable(true);
        JLabel L1 = new JLabel("Name");
        JLabel L2 = new JLabel("Code");
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add(L1);
        p1.add(L2);
   }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
     new S1();
    }

}
```

So when i'm writing this code in netbeans 8.1 the frame is coming but the buttons aren't coming on the frame.

Comment: You never add the panel to the JFrame

Answer (score 0):

you are not adding your jpanel to the jframe 
add this code to the constructor of the frame as the last 2 lines.

```
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
this.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

i dont recommend calling `setvisible` inside the constructor remove that line 
from the constructor and change this to

```
 new S1().setVisible(true);
```

in the main method